# jsdom hashchange event

Tags: node.js, hashchange, jsdom

On a [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) document:

```
document = require('jsdom').jsdom("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
window   = document.createWindow();
```

Changing its hash:

```
document.location.href = '#bang';
```

doesn't trigger any `'hashchange'` event on `window`

Does anyone aware of a workaround for this?

Thank you

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but normally you'd use `window.location.href = '#bang'` instead of `document`. Don't know enough about node.js though.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) docs

Try this before the rest of your code:

```
require('jsdom').defaultDocumentFeatures = {
  FetchExternalResources   : ['script'], 
  ProcessExternalResources : ['script'],
  MutationEvents           : '2.0',
  QuerySelector            : false
}

var window = jsdom.jsdom(body).createWindow();
```

Comment: Nice to remember the ability to set this bunch of options! However, I don't get how any of them affect the `hashchange` event... Am I missing something?